# Postfix: Allow sending to raw IP-address?

Tags: postfix

as I want to send mails to another internal server, i need the following address to be valid:

foobar@192.168.1.88

at the moment, postfix gives me the following error:

```
Mar 26 10:40:52 ludwig postfix/smtpd[11765]: warning: Illegal address syntax from localhost[127.0.0.1] in RCPT command: <foobar@192.168.1.88>
```

in another forum i saw these two config options, but they doesn't work anyway:

```
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
allow_min_user = yes
```

any advice how i can disable this RFC standard?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to add `resolve_numeric_domain = yes` into main.cf (Postfix 2.3+)

Comment: you don't need `allow_min_user` though. perhaps `strict_rfc821_envelopes` also but it depends on how clients are sending mail/connecting to mail server.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to work around the standards, why not incorporate the standards into your work.

First of all, as per RFC 5321, recipient@[ip.lit.er.al] is perfectly valid; unquoted, however, it is not.

Second, if you have postfix boxes that do not have a hostname, something is very wrong - correct this ASAP if you intend to maintain understandable mail services.